# Turn pandas dataframe into dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am running a for loop over a pandas dataframe that takes each row and creates a dictionary (of a sort) then uploads to an internal system.

The for loop isn't a problem, neither is the upload to the internal system. I cannot seem to get the format of the dictionary correct for the upload to proceed.

Here is a model of the dataframe:

```
    Id    Acct_num    Acct_Name   Prod   Date        Rev
0  1495   5001        Alpha       ret34  4/30/2020   4999
1  1496   5002        Beta        pro45  4/30/2020   18076
2  1497   5003        Gamma       sli55  4/30/2020   5671
3  1498   5004        Delta       ret34  4/30/2020   16683
```

[for better viewing if needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAzto.png)

I need each row of the dataframe to look like the below (first two rows):

```
1495:{'Acct_num':'5001', 'Acct_Name':'Alpha', 'Prod':'ret34', 'Date':'4/30/2020', 'Rev':'4999'}
1496:{'Acct_num':'5002', 'Acct_Name':'Beta', 'Prod':'pro45', 'Date':'4/30/2020', 'Rev':'18076'}
```

Here is what I have tried (with a few other variations, but to no avail):

```
for row in df.iloc[:,:].itertuples(index=False):
    if not row:
        break
    else:   
        d = row._asdict()
d
```

Which outputs an ordered dictionary like this:

```
OrderedDict([('Id', '1495),('Acct_num', '5001'),('Acct_Name', 'Alpha'),('Prod', 'ret34'), ('Date','2020-04-30'),('Rev',4999)])
```

Comment: your post is quite hard to read. Try to edit your code using  `` `. Same for the dateframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict) with orient="index"

> ‘index’ : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}

```
d = df.to_dict(orient="index")
d
{1495: {'Acct_num': 5001, 'Acct_Name': 'Alpha', 'Prod': 'ret34', 'Date': '4/30/2020', 'Rev': 4999}, 
1496: {'Acct_num': 5002, 'Acct_Name': 'Beta', 'Prod': 'pro45', 'Date': '4/30/2020', 'Rev': 18076}, 
1497: {'Acct_num': 5003, 'Acct_Name': 'Gamma', 'Prod': 'sli55', 'Date': '4/30/2020', 'Rev': 5671}, 
1498: {'Acct_num': 5004, 'Acct_Name': 'Delta', 'Prod': 'ret34', 'Date': '4/30/2020', 'Rev': 16683}}
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you, Dishin.  The format is what I was looking for, however, my for loop is now not working.  I need to iterate over one row (record) of the DF at a time.  When I try using the to_dict method I get an error that states: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_dict' on this code.  for row in df.iterrows():
    row1 = row.to_dict(orient="Index")

row1

Comment: You don't need `for` loop now. you can get expected output by just one line use only `d = df.to_dict(orient="index")`